# DataList doesn't show in input [HTML]

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4

Hi i have some problem with DataList in html, if i center whole site, dropdown menu in input doesn't show.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <input list="test">
    <datalist id="test">
        <option value="1"/>
        <option value="2"/>
        <option value="3"/>
        <option value="4"/>
        <option value="5"/>
    </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to fix it ;)
By the way whitch class in bootstrap make it'll look cool? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what browser are you using?  Trying to [reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-gwen-iq5cx?file=/index.html:221-248) what you are seeing, everything displays fine.

Comment: you're right im testing it on "Brave" and didn't test on other. Im so sory for wasteing your time.